# problem with firestore & rtc engine in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, webrtc, agora.io

I am having a problem with some internet connection in my app.
The problem is that **Cloud Firestore** doesn't work when I add **agora rtc engine** to the dependencies alongside with Cloud Firestore. Everything works fine in **debug mode**, but in **release mode**, when I open my app to make a test, everything works except Google Cloud Firestore. It wont load/write any data like there is no internet connection. When I remove agora rtc engine from **pubspec.yaml** dependencies, Cloud Firestore works back. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide more detailed information about your environment? Where are you running your app? Is it a mobile (iOS or Android?) or a web app? Have you tried other Google APIs appart from Cloud Firestore? Do they work?

Comment: It's an android release. Yes i tried other Google APIs like firebase auth and it worked without problems, the problem is only with cloud firestore

Comment: You can have a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59427#issuecomment-644585468) where a similar case is addressed. Please let me know if it is helpful.